# Manual installation on Ubuntu returns "gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)"

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compilation, imagemagick

I has some issues when I tried to install `Imagemagick` on Ubuntu `12.10`, so I tried to manually download it and install it.

But when I run the `make` command, I get this error statement:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/deployer/ImageMagick-6.8.9-6'
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-accelerate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-animate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-annotate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-artifact.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-attribute.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-blob.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cache.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cache-view.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-channel.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cipher.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-client.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-coder.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-color.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-colormap.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-colorspace.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-compare.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-composite.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-compress.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-configure.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-constitute.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-decorate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-distribute-cache.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-delegate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-deprecate.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-display.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-distort.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-draw.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-effect.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-enhance.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-exception.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-feature.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-fourier.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-fx.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-gem.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-geometry.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-hashmap.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-histogram.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-identify.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-image.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-image-view.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-layer.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-list.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-locale.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-log.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-magic.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-magick.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-matrix.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-memory.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mime.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-module.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-monitor.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-montage.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-morphology.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-opencl.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-option.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-paint.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pixel.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-policy.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-PreRvIcccm.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-prepress.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-property.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-profile.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-quantize.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-quantum.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-quantum-export.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-quantum-import.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-random.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-registry.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-resample.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-resize.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-resource.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-segment.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-semaphore.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-shear.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-signature.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-splay-tree.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-static.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-statistic.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-stream.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-string.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-thread.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-timer.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-token.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-transform.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-threshold.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-type.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-utility.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-version.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-widget.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xml-tree.lo
  CC       magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xwindow.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-aai.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-art.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-avs.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-bgr.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-bmp.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-braille.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cals.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-caption.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cin.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cip.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-clip.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cmyk.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-cut.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dcm.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dds.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-debug.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dib.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dng.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dot.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-dpx.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-fax.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-fd.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-fits.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-gif.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-gradient.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-gray.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-hald.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-hdr.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-histogram.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-hrz.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-html.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-icon.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-info.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-inline.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ipl.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-jnx.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-json.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-label.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mac.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-magick.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-map.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mask.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mat.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-matte.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-meta.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-miff.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mono.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mpc.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mpeg.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mpr.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-msl.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mtv.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-mvg.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-null.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-otb.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-palm.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pango.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pattern.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pcd.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pcl.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pcx.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pdb.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pdf.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pes.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pict.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pix.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-plasma.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pnm.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-preview.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ps.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ps2.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ps3.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-psd.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-pwp.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-raw.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-rgb.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-rgf.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-rla.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-rle.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-scr.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-screenshot.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-sct.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-sfw.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-sgi.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-stegano.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-sun.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-svg.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-tga.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-thumbnail.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-tile.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-tim.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ttf.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-txt.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-uil.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-url.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-uyvy.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-vicar.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-vid.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-viff.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-vips.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-wbmp.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-wpg.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xbm.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xc.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xcf.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xpm.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-xps.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-ycbcr.lo
  CC       coders/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-yuv.lo
  CC       filters/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-analyze.lo
  CCLD     magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-animate.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-compare.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-composite.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-conjure.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-convert.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-deprecate.lo
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickColorFloodfillImage':
wand/deprecate.c:1170:3: warning: 'ColorFloodfillImage' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:183) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickFlattenImages':
wand/deprecate.c:1240:3: warning: 'FlattenImages' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:137) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickMapImage':
wand/deprecate.c:1564:3: warning: 'MapImage' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:210) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickMatteFloodfillImage':
wand/deprecate.c:1636:3: warning: 'MatteFloodfillImage' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:214) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickMosaicImages':
wand/deprecate.c:1811:3: warning: 'MosaicImages' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:142) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickOpaqueImage':
wand/deprecate.c:1857:3: warning: 'MagickPaintOpaqueImage' is deprecated (declared at ./wand/deprecate.h:102) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickPaintOpaqueImage':
wand/deprecate.c:1958:3: warning: 'MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel' is deprecated (declared at ./wand/deprecate.h:104) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickRecolorImage':
wand/deprecate.c:2104:3: warning: 'RecolorImage' is deprecated (declared at ./magick/deprecate.h:148) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
wand/deprecate.c: In function 'MagickTransparentImage':
wand/deprecate.c:2348:3: warning: 'MagickPaintTransparentImage' is deprecated (declared at wand/deprecate.c:2010) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-display.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-drawing-wand.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-identify.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-import.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-magick-image.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-magick-property.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-magick-wand.lo
  CC       wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-mogrify.lo
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [wand/wand_libMagickWand_6_Q16_la-mogrify.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/deployer/ImageMagick-6.8.9-6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any tip how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means "out of memory". I've had it show up myself on a digital ocean droplet with only 512MB RAM. Upgrading memory should help. You can verify this buy trying what you do on a different server with more memory.